# Entity Framework 5 Eager Loading. How queries are built?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, eager-loading

Playing with EF5 I noticed something strange. Given these two classes and a simple query

```
public class Customer {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
} 

public class Order {
  public Customer Cust { get; set; }
  public Datetime DateOrdered { get; set; }
  ...
}

using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext(connstring))
{
 Customer c= ctx.customers.Include(x => x.orders).Where(x => x.Id == 1).Single<Customer>();

 foreach (Order o in c.orders)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
 }
}
```

I checked the SQL Server Profiler output and I think the query is unnecessary complex:

```sql
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[name] AS [name], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project1].[customer_Id] AS [customer_Id], 
[Project1].[timeordered] AS [timeordered]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[name] AS [name], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[customer_Id] AS [customer_Id], 
    [Extent2].[timeordered] AS [timeordered], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[name] AS [name]
        FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id] ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Extent2].[customer_Id]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

I'm sure i'm missing something but I don't know what, or is that the normal behavior of eager loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. In your simple case (1 include) you see EF doing the real query as a subquery, then it selects over it and applies ordering.

If you try including more includes in a single query, you will see the behaviour change, as it will start to do a single query per entity and then "union all" the queries together, and finally select over the result.

In my experience eager loading in EF leads almost always in a drop of performance, so I'd recommend avoiding it unless you have specific needs and you have deeply considered the performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

By using `Include`, you're saying that you want **one** database hit to result in **many** objects.

In order to do this, EF has to construct a suitable query *and* do further work with the results. Suppose we have a table `A` and each `A` has many `B`s. In particular, there are two `A`s and each has three (different) `B`s. Suppose we ask for `A.Include("B")`. EF constructs a query that has a resultset essentially like this:

```
AId    AProp1    AProp2     BId    BAId   BProp1   BProp2
1      xxx       yyy        56     1      aaa      bbb
1      xxx       yyy        57     1      ccc      ddd
1      xxx       yyy        58     1      eee      fff
2      www       zzz        101    2      ggg      ggg
2      www       zzz        102    2      jjj      kkk
2      www       zzz        103    2      mmm      nnn
```

EF then uses this data to construct two `A` objects, six `B` objects, and populates each `A`'s `B` collection appropriately.

That's what you're asking for with eager loading - you want fewer database calls but more data returned in each.

Additionally: the `C1` column is (I would guess) an indicator column to say whether a particular `A` has `B`s; and the `TOP (2)` is because you asked for `Single`, so it has to be able to distinguish between 1 and more than 1 records existing.